# Qt wont send POST data

Tags: qt, post

I am trying to send POST data to a php page using QT.  My code is as follows:

```
#include <QHttp>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QString>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <iostream>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QObject>
....
void Transmissions::Send()
{
 QUrl serviceUrl = QUrl("http://192.168.1.138/postTest.php");
 QByteArray postData;
 QString username="user="+User.Email()+"&";
 QString Passwd="password="+User.Pass();
 postData.append(username);
 postData.append(Passwd);

 QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
 QObject::connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
 networkManager->post(QNetworkRequest(serviceUrl), postData);
}
....
void serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
 QString data = reply->readAll();
    cerr << data.toStdString()<<endl;

}
```

Now, This code will not compile.  These are the errors:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘QNetworkAccessManager::QNetworkAccessManager(Transmissions* const)’
```

and

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘QObject::connect(QNetworkAccessManager*&, const char*, Transmissions* const, const char*)’
```

Now according to this [How can I POST data to a url using QNetworkAccessManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599423/how-can-i-post-data-to-a-url-using-qnetworkaccessmanager) and the QT documentation here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html I am doing everything right.  Heck I can even copy and paste the code from the QT Docs site and get the same error.  What am I missing here?

EDIT
if I try the post method shown here [How to send data back from PHP after a HTTP Post in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794600/how-to-send-data-back-from-php-after-a-http-post-in-qt)
I get this:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationAdded(QNetworkConfiguration) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationAdded(QNetworkConfiguration)
```

please someone help

**EDIT2**:
Thanks to VitaminP my code now compiles.  But now this issue is happening:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationAdded(QNetworkConfiguration) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationAdded(QNetworkConfiguration)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationRemoved(QNetworkConfiguration) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationRemoved(QNetworkConfiguration)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationUpdateComplete() to QNetworkConfigurationManager::updateCompleted()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::onlineStateChanged(bool) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::onlineStateChanged(bool)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationChanged(QNetworkConfiguration) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationChanged(QNetworkConfiguration)
```

Comment: What are the objects/methods you're trying to connect?
(null)::configurationAdded looks like either the object creation failed, or perhaps even it wasn't MOCed (all objects that you want to connect have to extend QObject and have the Q_OBJECT macro in the class definition.

Comment: I think the problem (from Edit2) is that your slots aren't a member of your `Transmissions` class, it's just a standalone function. Make your header file look like : `class Transmissions : public QObject() { slots: void configurationAdded(..); void configurationRemoved(...);}` etc.

Comment: @docsteer, your right. I never put those in my header. I found some documentation here doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qnetworkconfigurationmanager.html  Looks like I didn't do my reading on signals and slots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's this line:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
```

This is wrong, you're trying to construct it with a pointer to Transmissions (through "this"), which I'm guessing is one of your classes. Replace it with:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager;
```

You can only pass the this pointer if it points to a `QObject` (see the docs you linked on Qt). Alternatively, you can have your class extend `QObject`.

Since Transmissions doesn't extend `QObject`, then the `connect(...)` won't work when you pass in "this" either.

Comment: you sir are a saint. There is one problem, I am getting a bunch of errors.  I updated my question.